# AddTarget to UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, delegates

I'm writing my own custom control which is implemented through `UIView`.

And when I initialize it, I would like to add a custom target to it like this:

```
[myControl addTarget:self action:@selector(turnOn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

I do this so when I change something on my UIView, it would trigger that sort of method in its parent control. I am aware that there's a **delegate** for such purposes, but I was wondering if it is possible to do without it.

How do you do this sort of thing in Objective-C? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instead subclass `UIContol` you can invoke

```
- (void)sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

from within your subclass, and that will trigger the action

Comment: That's a great idea, but I actually need to control the whole `view` of it and its `frame`, is it possible with `UIControl`?

Comment: `UIControl` is itself a subclass of `UIView`, so anything you can do with `UIView` you can do with `UIControl`, but you get the added benefit of being able to send actions for events